Нужна ли запятая после "преданной"?
Она оказалась преданной(?) совсем как тогда, в детстве.

Правильно:
Она оказалась прЕданной, совсем как тогдА, в дЕтстве.
Пояснение

Решение интонационное, но практически желательно использовать именно такой вариант.

В то же время вариант без обособления грамматически возможен:


Она оказалась преданной совсем как тогдА, // в дЕтстве.
Сравнить (для глагола): Ее предали совсем как тогдА, в дЕтстве.

Объяснение такое: при постановке только одной запятой (вариант с причастием) первую часть предложения сложно произнести в одну фонетическую фразу, вся конструкция получается неуравновешенной.


Спасибо! Скажите, пожалуйста, а разве тут нет сравнения, требующего постановки запятой? "Ее предали совсем как тогда".

По Розенталю сочетания как правило, как исключение, как обычно, как всегда, как прежде, как сейчас, как теперь, как нарочно  обособляются факультативно, то есть нет обособления при тесной связи со сказуемым.// Влияние "совсем"?  Как мне думается,  это слово может влиять на обстоятельство образа действия, а у нас обстоятельство времени.  Здесь оно, наоборот, способствует обособлению.  Она оказалась преданной – самодостаточное сообщение,  вторую часть даже тире можно обособить (есть такие примеры в Нацкорпусе).
